# GraphAPI query MailboxType

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

is it possible to query the Mailbox Type of a user also via GraphAPI?

When i'm using the "GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%22) a lot of general information is displayed. i know, not every user synced to azure must have a mailbox, but in case, the user got a mailbox - is it possible to query the mailbox type?

Thanks
br

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to query a Mailbox Type using Graph API.

You can get the Mailbox type information using Exchange PowerShell, Get-Mailbox under RecipientTypeDetails parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Please mark the answer as verified, if it was useful to you. Thank you.